# проверка наличия header в ответе сервера

Tags: c#, xamarin, httpclient

Разрабатываю приложение xamarin, возникла необходимость при любых http-запросах просматривать headerы ответа и сохранять определенный header, если он существует, в память телефона. Для работы с сетью использую RestEase. Возможно ли сделать какой-то обработчик для проверки заголовков на уровне httpClient?

Answer (score 0):

Так пробовали?

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var myawesomeResponse = await client.GetAsync("");
    var responseHeaders = myawesomeResponse.Headers;
}
```